# What do I do when I get a 1020 cloudfare error in my api?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests, cloudflare

I am working on a small python project which posts to [Sharechat](https://apis.sharechat.com).

When I run my API code, I get a Cloudfare error informing me of a 1020 error. Since it is long, I have added it to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/jMuYhfaj). I have checked other parts of my code and the Authorization headers. How do I fix this?

My code:

```py
params = {"language": lang}
endpoint = self.BASE + "getTrendingTags"

res = requests.get(url=endpoint, params=params, headers={"Authorization": f'Bearer {self.token}'})
print(res.text)
```